# How to add additional columns to CSV in C#

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I've created a small C# program to get a CSV file, modify the data, split some line items up, and also add additional columns of data. This last part is introducing errors when run.

`Error: Header with name 'Payee_Country'[0] was not found. Header with name 'Payer_Address1'[0] was not found. Header with name 'Payer_Address2'[0] was not found. Header with name 'Payer_City'[0] was not found. Header with name 'Payer_State' [0] was not found. Header with name 'Payer_Zip'[0] was not found. Header with name 'Payer_Country'[0] was not found.`

The following code is what I have so far, for example the values used above are not pre-existing in the CSV input file and I'm not sure how to get this working, as I've tried mapping but that just introduced more errors.

```
    public class CsvRecord
    {
        public string GLAccountName { get; set; }
        public string BankRoutingNumber { get; set; }
        public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
        public DateOnly FileDate { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceNumbers { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceDates { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceAmounts { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceTotals { get; set; }
        public string InvoiceDescriptions { get; set; }
        public string CheckNumber { get; set; }
        public string VendorID { get; set; }
        public string VendorName { get; set; }
        public string VendorAddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string VendorAddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string VendorCity { get; set; }
        public string VendorState { get; set; }
        public string VendorZip { get; set; }
        public string Payee_Country { get; set; }
        public string VendorEmail { get; set; }
        public string Payer_Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Payer_Address2 { get; set; }
        public string Payer_City { get; set; }
        public string Payer_State { get; set; }
        public string Payer_Zip { get; set; }
        public string Payer_Country { get; set; }
    }




    private void SelectFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            FilePathTextBox.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void RunButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePathTextBox.Text))
        {
            try
            {
                // Read the CSV file
                List<CsvRecord> records;

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(FilePathTextBox.Text))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
                {
                    records = csv.GetRecords<CsvRecord>().ToList();
                }

                // Create a new list to store the modified records
                List<CsvRecord> modifiedRecords = new List<CsvRecord>();

                // Split records containing pipes

                foreach (var record in records)
                {

                    var invoiceAmountsArray = record.InvoiceAmounts.Split('|');
                    var invoiceTotalsArray = record.InvoiceTotals.Split('|');
                    var invoiceNumbersArray = record.InvoiceNumbers.Split('|');
                    var invoiceDatesArray = record.InvoiceDates.Split('|');
                    var invoiceDescriptionsArray = record.InvoiceDescriptions.Split('|');

                    // Ensure the arrays have the same length
                    int itemCount = Math.Min(invoiceAmountsArray.Length, invoiceTotalsArray.Length);

                    // Create separate line items for each amount
                    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
                    {
                        var newRecord = new CsvRecord
                        {
                            GLAccountName = record.GLAccountName.Trim(' ', '"'),
                            Payer_Address1 = "xxx",
                            Payer_Address2 = "xxx",
                            Payer_City = "xxx",
                            Payer_State = "xxx",
                            Payer_Zip = "xxx",
                            Payer_Country = "US",
                            BankRoutingNumber = record.BankRoutingNumber.Trim(' ', '"'),
                            BankAccountNumber = record.BankAccountNumber.Trim(' ', '"'),
                            FileDate = record.FileDate,
                            Amount = record.Amount,
                            InvoiceNumbers = invoiceNumbersArray[i].Trim(' ', '"'),
                            InvoiceDates = invoiceDatesArray[i].Trim(' ', '"'),
                            InvoiceAmounts = invoiceAmountsArray[i].Trim(' ', '"'),
                            InvoiceTotals = invoiceTotalsArray[i].Trim(' ', '"'),
                            InvoiceDescriptions = invoiceDescriptionsArray[i].Trim(' ', '"'),
                            CheckNumber = record.CheckNumber.Trim(' ', '"'),
                            VendorID = record.VendorID.Trim(' ', '"'),
                            VendorName = record.VendorName.Trim(' ', '"'),
                            VendorAddressLine1 = record.VendorAddressLine1.Trim(' ', '"'),
                            VendorAddressLine2 = record.VendorAddressLine2.Trim(' ', '"'),
                            VendorCity = record.VendorCity.Trim(' ', '"'),
                            VendorState = record.VendorState.Trim(' ', '"'),
                            VendorZip = record.VendorZip.Trim(' ', '"'),
                            Payee_Country = "US",
                            VendorEmail = record.VendorEmail.Trim(' ', '"')
                        };

                        // Add the new record to the list
                        modifiedRecords.Add(newRecord);
                    }
                }

                // Perform your edits on the 'records' list here

                foreach (var record in modifiedRecords)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(record.CheckNumber) && !record.CheckNumber.All(char.IsDigit))
                    {
                        record.CheckNumber = "";
                    }

                    record.BankRoutingNumber = record.BankRoutingNumber.PadLeft(9, '0');
                    record.BankAccountNumber = record.BankAccountNumber.PadLeft(13, '0');
                    record.CheckNumber = record.CheckNumber.PadLeft(10, '0');

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.VendorID) && record.VendorID.Length > 17)
                    {

                        record.VendorID = record.VendorID.Substring(0, 17);
                    }

                    decimal tempValue = decimal.Parse(record.Amount);
                    record.Amount = tempValue.ToString("F2");

                    tempValue = decimal.Parse(record.InvoiceTotals);
                    record.InvoiceTotals = tempValue.ToString("F2");

                    tempValue = decimal.Parse(record.InvoiceAmounts);
                    record.InvoiceAmounts = tempValue.ToString("F2");

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.InvoiceNumbers) && record.InvoiceNumbers.Length > 30)
                    {

                        record.InvoiceNumbers = record.InvoiceNumbers.Substring(0, 30);
                    }

                    record.FileDate = DateOnly.ParseExact(record.FileDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    DateTime tempDate = DateTime.Parse(record.InvoiceDates);
                    record.InvoiceDates = tempDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    record.InvoiceDescriptions = record.InvoiceDescriptions.Trim(' ', '"');

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.InvoiceDescriptions) && record.InvoiceDescriptions.Length > 50)
                    {

                        record.InvoiceDescriptions = record.InvoiceDescriptions.Substring(0, 50);
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.GLAccountName) && record.GLAccountName.Length > 35)
                    {

                        record.GLAccountName = record.GLAccountName.Substring(0, 35);
                    }
                }

                // Save the modified CSV file to the desktop
                var desktopPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                var outputPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Fixed_IP.csv");

                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputPath))
                using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                { HasHeaderRecord = false }))
                {
                    csv.WriteRecords(modifiedRecords);
                }

                MessageBox.Show($"File converted and saved to: {outputPath}", "Success", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a file first.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Guess: May be you can't use names with underscore `_`.

Comment: @PoulBak removing the underscores makes no difference, I get the same error message. It seems to be caused by the original CSV file not containing those headers, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Looking at the source on github for Writer, when writing a field to the file, the code checks if the value should be quoted. Have you tried doing something like converting the values to be assigned to their string representation(Payer_Country = string.Format("{0}", "US")); https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvWriter.cs

Comment: Shouldn't make any different what the original file looks like; when CsvHelper writes a new file it uses the properties it sees on the entities written to work out the headers. The fact that you have to trim quotes off every field seems like a quote char kisxonfiguration. Show a sample of the CSV file in your code. This code is also more complex than needed. You should be able to just enumerate the list you get from GetRecords and modify the entities to populate the properties then write them back to disk

Comment: Even better you could just code those missing properties to be backed directly by the relevant pipe delimited strings and have them as readonly so all you do is read it in and write it out again straight away

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

> It seems to be caused by the original CSV file not containing those headers

When you use `csv.GetRecords<CsvRecord>().ToList()`, CsvHelper is expecting those headers to be in the original file, but you can fix it by marking those properties as optional.

Either directly on the class

```cs
public class CsvRecord
{
   public string GLAccountName { get; set; }
   ...
   [Optional]
   public string Payee_Country { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Or via a `ClassMap`

```cs
Map(m => m.Payee_Country).Optional();
```